# Is it possible to give a custom description to a native Blender property in my UIPanel?

Tags: python, node-editor

Trying to figure out if some dirty trick to add an input description of unconnected sockets in the UI panel.

I can access both the socket input properties, but obviously these have the description "Input value used for unconnected socket"

I know I could make a custom property that update this property with a callback, and then add a `description = ""` but I don't like it, it's slow and doesn't update during animations. So I discarded the idea.

Anyone know anything about it?

[image]

```
    import bpy
    class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
        """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
        bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
        bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
        bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
        bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
        bl_context = "object"
    
        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
    
            scn = context.scene
            node = scn.world.node_tree.nodes.get('My Group')
            
            ### Trivial example:
            descriptions = {0:"This is a FloatVectorProperty",
                            1:"This is a FloatProperty"} 
            ###

            if node:
                for idx, input in enumerate(node.inputs):
                    tip = descriptions.get(idx)
                    layout.prop(input,'default_value',text=input.name)
    
    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/D9967

Comment: It seems that for now it is not possible even with a dirty make-up. We hope they implement this possibility. It would be a fantastic opportunity.